# Python: Knight's Shortest Path on 0-63 Chessboard

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shortest-path

Problem:

Given input(x, y), find a Knight's shortest path from x to y, on a chessboard numbered 0-63 (row 1: 0-8, row 2: 9-15, etc.).

I began to solve this problem using Numpy, but 1. It turns out I'm not allowed to use Numpy, and 2. My code is getting way too complex anyway. There must be a more simple way to solve this problem.

Here is my (unfinished) code, which tackles the first two moves of a BFS search:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
[16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23],
[24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31],
[32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39],
[40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47],
[48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55],
[56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63]])



def answer(src, dest):
''' Takes integer inputs, converts them to board coordinates '''
    x = np.argwhere(a==src)
    y = np.argwhere(a==dest)
    z = [tuple(l) for l in x]

''' Returns all possible moves from starting position, in coordinates '''
def knight_move(p):
    offset1 = np.array([[-2,-1],[-2,1],[2,-1],[2,1]])    
    idx = np.row_stack((offset1, offset1[:,::-1])) + p    
    return idx[~((idx < 0) | (idx > 7)).any(1)]

''' Checks smallest number of moves from start to end position '''
for i in z:
    mv1 = knight_move(i) #finds possible first moves
    b = a[mv1[:,0], mv1[:,1]] #converts from coordinates to integers
    if dest in b:
        return 1
    elif dest not in b:
        c = np.array(mv1).tolist() #converts mv1 to iterable list
        d = [tuple(e) for e in c] #converts list to tuples for knight_move
        blah = np.concatenate([knight_move(f) for f in d]).tolist() #returns coordinates of all possible second moves
        r = [tuple(m) for m in blah]
        h = np.asarray(r)
        w = a[h[:,0], h[:,1]]
        if dest in w:
            return 2
```

I know I am attacking this the wrong way. I'm assuming there is a relatively simple approach, that I just don't know. How, using only the standard python libraries (or using none at all), can I solve this problem?